# Read data from index.html into logic.js

Tags: javascript

I have an index.html file that is getting data from app.py (pulling from MongoDB) using render_template and I am attempting to read the data loaded in the index.html into my logic.js so I can create a leaflet map. However, it seems that the data is not loading in my logic.js. Any thoughts?

Here is my index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Visualization</title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
    integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

      <!-- Leaflet CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.css"
  integrity="sha512-xwE/Az9zrjBIphAcBb3F6JVqxf46+CDLwfLMHloNu6KEQCAWi6HcDUbeOfBIptF7tcCzusKFjFw2yuvEpDL9wQ=="
  crossorigin="" />
  <!-- Leaflet JavaScript code -->
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.js"
  integrity="sha512-gZwIG9x3wUXg2hdXF6+rVkLF/0Vi9U8D2Ntg4Ga5I5BZpVkVxlJWbSQtXPSiUTtC0TjtGOmxa1AJPuV0CPthew=="
  crossorigin=""></script>

  <!-- Our CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/css/style.css">

</head>

<body>
  <div id="map"></div>
  <div class="container text-center">
    <h1 class="p-3 mb-2 bg-secondary text-white">Map Visualization</h1>
  </div>

  <!-- confirm that data is loaded -->
  <!-- {% for i in html_results %}
    <h5>{{i}}</h5>
  {%endfor%} -->
  <script>
    let html_results = JSON.parse("{{html_results | tojson | safe}}")
  </script>
  <script src="{{url_for('static', filename='/js/logic.js')}}"></script>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: that's `ejs` and if You use express framework look for view engine attachment

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-ejs-to-template-your-node-application